# ASSET::URL not working in external php file in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a php file which is in the name of index.php. In that I have included another page like **"xyz.php"**.

I have included **"xyz.php"** in **index.php** using `@include('xyz')`.

When I am trying to include external css and js in xyz using

```
{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jsfile.js') }}


{{ URL::asset('assets/css/cssfile.css') }}
```

It is not working. In source it displays as it is.

How can I solve this issue.

## index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>My Laravel page</title>    
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   
      <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/netbramha/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/netbramha/js/modernizr.custom.js') }}"></script>    
   </head>
   <body>

    @include('home-search')

   </body>
</html>
```

## home-search.blade.php

```
<div class="video-modal">
      <img class="lazy-load" data-original="{{ URL::asset('/') }}/assets/netbramha/images/video-img.jpg" src="images/grey.gif" width="598" height="336" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
{{ URL::asset('/') }}/location of you css/scripts
```

cheers

Comment: @rsvijay can post your source code? Check you source code and see  the location for your asset

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **helper functions**

`include(public_path() . '/xyz.php')`

Answer (score 0):

You are using blade templating in the xyz.php file. It should be named xyz.blade.php